# How to execute a particular Ansible module with a different user instead of the PLAY user

Tags: file, ansible, ansible-2.x

Here is my playbook:

```
- name: Play 4.
  hosts: dest_nodes
  user: "{{ USER }}"

  tasks:

   - name: "Load Respective variable file before Deployment1."
     tags: deploy
     include_vars:
 file: "{{ item }}"
     with_fileglob:
       - "vars/{{ Layer }}_*.yaml"

   - file:
       path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/gitfiles/{{ Number }}"
       state: directory
     when: Layer == 'APP'
     with_items:
       - "{{ Source_Filenames.split(',') }}"


   - name: "Pulling APP files  `{{ inventory_hostname }}`"
     tags: deploy
     synchronize:
       src: "{{ BASEPATH }}/ref.txt"
       dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/gitfiles/{{ Number }}"
       mode: pull
     register: q
     when: Layer == 'APP'
     with_items:
       - "{{ Source_Filenames.split(',') }}"
```

In the above playbook i wish everything to be executed with "{{ USER }}" however, the below file module should run the the local user "user1" that executes my playbook.

```
   - file:
       path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/gitfiles/{{ Number }}"
       state: directory
     when: Layer == 'APP'
     with_items:
       - "{{ Source_Filenames.split(',') }}"
```

I understand that the solution lies in become_user but don't know how to specify become_user for the file module only.

Can you please suggest what changes I need to make to the file module / my playbook ?

Comment: use `block` structure for instance, or split playbook into two separate ones

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `user` is deprecated, you should use `remote_user` instead.

Now your question is not clear. There are actually 2 possibilities:

1. You want to always connect as `{{ USER }}` and become (e.g. `sudo`) `user1` for a specific task.
2. You want to connect as `{{ USER }}` for all tasks except for a specific task where you want to connect as `user1`

The first scenario is by far the most common one. Example below is for pure illustration, debug will not actually `become` anything:

```
---
- name: my play
  hosts: my_hosts
  remote_user: my_deploy_user

  tasks:
    - name: normal task
      debug:
        msg: "normal"

    - name: become root task
      debug:
        msg: "as root"
      become: true

    - name: become user1 task
      debug:
        msg: "as user1"
      become: true
      become_user: user1
```

Now, if you really want to connect as an other user, this is also possible (provided your have the correct config/keys to do so). Once more, example is for pure illustration:

```
- name: my_play
  hosts: my_hosts
  remote_user: "{{ USER }}"

  tasks:
    - name: task as usual
      debug:
        msg: "Usual task"

    - name: task connected as user1
      debug:
        msg: "connect as user1
      remote_user: user1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to apply the become user at the task you want it, at the module level:

```
- file:
    path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/gitfiles/{{ Number }}"
    state: directory
  when: Layer == 'APP'
  with_items:
    - "{{ Source_Filenames.split(',') }}"
  become: true
  become_user: <new user>
```